# Content loading before eventlistener is ''clicked''

Tags: javascript, foreach, click

I was following along a tutorial about 15 JS projects, and I pause and try to solve the project on my own before watching but I am a little stuck, I wanted to do it a bit different to get better with promises and to see how it is to use data outside of hardcoded one.

So I created a local JSON file and tried pulling the data but when the page is loaded the first iteration already is loaded and since the 'click' event didn't happen the data should not be displayed? (This confuses me a lot). Also the click event doesn't work and my currentItem isn't incrementing so it won't change when the click event happens so the next iteration won't change

```
let currentItem = 1;
    // Event Listener for next button
nextBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  getData()
    .then(function nextBtn(data) {
      Reviews(data);

      currentItem++;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
);

// Get data from local or api
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch("reviews.json");

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

// Display data in the UI
function Reviews(review) {
  review.forEach(function (data) {
    if (currentItem === data.id) {
      personImg.src = data.img;
      personaName.innerHTML = data.name;
      personJob.innerHTML = data.job;
      personInfo.innerHTML = data.text;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the second parameter you're passing into `addEventListener`.

This parameter is supposed to be a function. This function will get executed when the click occurs.

However you're not passing it a function, you're actually calling the function `getData()`.

I suspect what you really want is

```
nextBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => getData()
    .then(function nextBtn(data) {
      Reviews(data);

      currentItem++;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
);
```

Note that all I did was put `() =>` before `getData()`, which makes it a function that doesn't get executed until the click actually occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! For some reason I thought that I don't need to pass it in a function